# Javascript Dynamic Image Preview (generated from database)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some trouble as I need to preview multiple images from multiple inputs that are generated from database.

I really need multiple inputs since I need to create an array based on language. (My inputs are generated amongst the languages in database, so it creates ID's like img[en], img[fr], img[es]. Then I upload it based on the language (en, fr, es).

I also have some divs for image preview generated the same way (in this case, imgpreview[en], imgpreview[es]).

The simple code for one image works good, but I need that javascript dinamically can associate all divs to inputs since the database languages could be several.

The code I used to use for one input, only works for one input.
Can you please guide me in how could I achieve this?

The code for one input:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="input-file-now">Image</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
            <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i> <span class="fileinput-filename"></span></div> <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file"> <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span> <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
            <input type="file" name="imgfile" id="imgfile"> </span> <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a> </div>
    </div>                                               
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#imgfile").on('change', function () {

var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();

if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                    "class": "img-responsive"
            }).appendTo(image_holder);

        }
        image_holder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Pls select only images");
}
});
</script>
```